# RegEx capturing string several lines behind

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following sample text that I'm trying to create a capture for.:

```
object-group network og-n-sna-EWB-UAT-srvrs-4
 network-object host 10.34.68.108
 network-object host 10.34.68.109
 network-object host 10.34.68.110
object-group network og-n-bng-ind-users
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1025
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1741
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1344
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1193
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR06L1318
object-group network og-n-mdm-srvrs-7
 network-object host 10.36.50.101
 network-object host 10.36.50.102
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to capture the name of the object group (**og-n-bng-ind-users**) that the object **obj-FAIBLR04L1344** is a part of.
I've tried combining
`*\snetwork-object\sobject\sobj-FAIBLR04L1344*` with a look behind, but I can't get it to work. Does anyone have any idea on how to construct this regular expression to work with PowerShell?

Comment: PowerShell uses PCRE-like Regular Expressions so it shouldn't be that different than other languages. *In .NET, regular expression patterns are defined by a special syntax or language, which is compatible with Perl 5 regular expressions and adds some additional features such as right-to-left matching.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Comment: You dont' need a lookbehind, you could use a capturing group `^object-group network (\S+)(?>\r?\n(?!object-group network).*)*\r?\n.*obj-FAIBLR04L1344` https://regex101.com/r/e8pslV/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want RegEx here?

Prepare:

```
$text = @'
object-group network og-n-sna-EWB-UAT-srvrs-4
 network-object host 10.34.68.108
 network-object host 10.34.68.109
 network-object host 10.34.68.110
object-group network og-n-bng-ind-users
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1025
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1741
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1344
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1193
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR06L1318
object-group network og-n-mdm-srvrs-7
 network-object host 10.36.50.101
 network-object host 10.36.50.102
'@

$networkObjectId = 'obj-FAIBLR04L1344' + [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Variant:

```
$objectGroupListFound = @($text.Split([string[]]@('object-group'), [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) |
    Where-Object { $_.Contains( "network-object object $($networkObjectId)" ) } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine)[0]} |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Split()[-1]} )

if ($objectGroupListFound.Count -ne 1) 
{
    Write-Error "No objectGroup found for networkObjectId $($networkObjectId) or found more than one. Found $($objectGroupListFound.Count)." 
}
## There I omit "else", assuming code upper is wrapped into try block and on error, it will not reach this line.
$objectGroup = $objectGroupListFound[0]
```

Variant:

```
$tempText = $text.Substring(0,$text.IndexOf($networkObjectId))
$tempText = $tempText.Substring($tempText.LastIndexOf('object-group'))
$objectGroup = $tempText.Split("`r`n".ToCharArray(), [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Split(' ', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[2]
```

Variant (line by line) - I think it is most simple and clear

```
$text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($path)
# or  $text = $text.Split([char[]]"`r`n", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

$networkObjectId = "obj-FAIBLR04L1344"

$objectGroupCache = $null
$objectGroup = $null
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $text.Count; $i++)
{
    if ($text[$i].Trim().StartsWith('object-group network'))
    {
        # We are entering this group.
        $objectGroupCache =$text[$i].Split([char[]]" `t", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[-1]
    }
    elseif ($text[$i].Trim().StartsWith('network-object') -and $text[$i].Trim().EndsWith($networkObjectId))
    {
        $objectGroup = $objectGroupCache
        break;
    }
}

if ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($objectGroup))
{
    Write-Error "Not found" 
}
```

Comment: Why `'obj-FAIBLR04L1344' + [System.Environment]::NewLine` as opposed to just ``"obj-FAIBLR04L1344`n"``?

Comment: @NekoMusume, **1)** because I guess, `$networkObjectId` may be a variable in some loop.  **2)** On Windows, it should be  \`r\`n , and not \`n . `NewLine` keeps default OS newline sequence. Depending on file and method, it can me "$($var)\`r\`n" or "$($var)\`n"

Comment: Thank you @filimonic. This worked perfectly and has decent performance in my larger sample of more than 200.000 lines

Comment: @MartinWJørgensen if you need `one-time` lookups on the same file, better use `glogg` text viewer (64-bit only). It indexes text files for almost online search and opens files more than 2 Gbytes in few seconds. @ http://glogg.bonnefon.org/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text is stored in `text.txt`, I believe this could work:

```powershell
Get-Content -Raw text.txt |
  Select-String `
    -AllMatches `
    -Pattern '(?<=object-group network ).+(?=(\s*network-object object .*)*\s*network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1344)' |
  foreach {$_.Matches.Value}
```

`Get-Content -Raw` passes the content of `text.txt` as a single object (multiline string) to `Select-String`. The `-AllMatches` option shows all the matches instead of just the first one (in case the object is in several groups in your example text). The `-Pattern` option receives the pattern to search. This pattern uses a lookbehind for `object-group network`  and a lookahead for zero or more `\s*network-object object .*` followed by `\s*network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1344`.

`Select-String` prints matching lines (the whole text in this case). To avoid this, `foreach {$_.Matches.Value}` iterates on the matches and prints its value.

Comment: This one worked in a small sample, but in my full configuration that had more than 200.000 lines of text, it took forever to run through just one of the objects (I had more than 3000 of them in a loop)
I suppose this has something to do with the performance of the regex in larger strings

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use ConvertFrom-String. This works on your small sample data. It's quite possible there needs to be more "training" data for the template. The [technology](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/flashextract-framework-data-extraction-examples/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fum%2Fpeople%2Fsumitg%2Fpubs%2Fpldi14-flashextract.pdf) it's built on is amazing.

```
$template = @'
object-group network og-n-sna-EWB-UAT-srvrs-4
 network-object host 10.34.68.108
 network-object host 10.34.68.109
 network-object host 10.34.68.110
object-group network {Name: og-n-bng-ind-users}
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1025
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1741
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1344
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1193
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR06L1318
object-group network og-n-mdm-srvrs-7
 network-object host 10.36.50.101
 network-object host 10.36.50.102
'@

@'
object-group network og-n-sna-EWB-UAT-srvrs-4
 network-object host 10.34.68.108
 network-object host 10.34.68.109
 network-object host 10.34.68.110
object-group network og-n-bng-ind-users
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1025
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1741
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1344
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR04L1193
 network-object object obj-FAIBLR06L1318
object-group network og-n-mdm-srvrs-7
 network-object host 10.36.50.101
 network-object host 10.36.50.102
'@ | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
```

Or from a file

```
Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template

Name              
----              
og-n-bng-ind-users
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0):

You could also opt to parse the whole file into an array of PSObjects, which not only makes it easy to get any item you seek, but it also allows you to save the file as CSV file to use in Excel for instance.

```
$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\thefile.txt' {
    '^object-group network ' { $group = ($_.Trim() -split '\s')[-1] }
    'network-object' { 
        $item = $_.Trim() -split '\s'
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Group = $group
            Type  = $item[1]
            Value = $item[2]
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have this file converted to an object array, you can get anything
you need from it, like the object group name for Value 'obj-FAIBLR04L1344'

```
($result | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq 'obj-FAIBLR04L1344' }).Group  # --> og-n-bng-ind-users
```